# How to draw a sketch in the screen with javascript or html5 and correct all the desviations in lines?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm currently using paper.js for an app to draw concept sketches of forniture desing. Drawing on the screen with a pencil makes lines not straight.

Is there any component that can "guess" that you are drawing a straight line and correct it?

Comment: If you want a straight line you can use `var path = new Path.Line(new Point(20, 20), new Point(120, 120));`

Comment: I would like to draw the line and then autocorrect desviations, something like check the path and if the desviation between points is between a margin convert it to a straight line